# Which is a good solution to center the layouts in this way?(android xml)

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

I don't want to use too many linear layouts to set the gravity center. Is there a better solution? Thanks!
[image]

This is the solution with linear layouts but someone told me I need to make this using relative layout because using too many linear layouts is causes slow rendering, but i did not succed with relative layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dan.movietracker.fragments.HomeFragment">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/action"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
          />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advendure_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/adventure"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/animation_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/animation"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_genres"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comedy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/comedy"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/crime_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/crime"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/documntary_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/documentary"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_genres"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drama_Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/drama"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/family_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/crime"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fantasy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/documentary"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_genres"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/history_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/history"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/horror_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/horror"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/music_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/music"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_genres"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mystery_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/mystery"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/romance_Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/romance"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scienceFiction_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/science_fiction"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_genres"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thriller_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:text="@string/thriller"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/war_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/war"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_genres"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/western_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/genresTextBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_genres"
            android:text="@string/western"
            android:textColor="@color/genresTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you at least include code for your best attempt to generate this activity layout?

Comment: At least put some your xml code.

Comment: I add the code with linear layouts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way doing this is to create `item_layout.xml` and add below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerButton"
        android:text="Mistery"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Romance"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerButton"
        android:text="Science Fiction"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then everytime u add something u can use it as row item layout. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but i need to use a relative layout.

Comment: So I can change it to rel layout

Comment: Thank you very much! It is possible to make this with only one Relative layout?